# Uncaught TypeError: Property description must be an object: c during Object.defineProperty()

Tags: javascript

I'd like to add 'compatibility' property in each browsers[browser]:

```
            const browsers = {
                'android': {
                    regex: /Android\s\d{1,2}/,
                    version: '4.4',
                },
                'safari': {
                    regex: /(?:Mac|iPhone)(?:.*Version\/)(\d{1,2})/,
                    version: 9,
                },
                'chrome': {
                    regex: /(?<=Chrome\/)\d{1,2}|(?<=CriOS\/)\d{1,2}/,
                    version: 45,
                },
                'firefox': {
                    regex: /(?<=Firefox\/)\d{1,2}|(?<=FxiOS\/)d\{1,2}/,
                    version: 38,
                },
                'opera': {
                    regex: /(?<=OPR\/)\d{1,2}/,
                    version: 30,
                },
            };
```

to

```
            const browsers = {
                'android': {
                    regex: /Android\s\d{1,2}/,
                    version: '4.4',
                    compatibility: ?,
                },
                'safari': {
                    regex: /(?:Mac|iPhone)(?:.*Version\/)(\d{1,2})/,
                    version: 9,
                    compatibility: ?,
                },
                'chrome': {
                    regex: /(?<=Chrome\/)\d{1,2}|(?<=CriOS\/)\d{1,2}/,
                    version: 45,
                    compatibility: ?,
                },
                'firefox': {
                    regex: /(?<=Firefox\/)\d{1,2}|(?<=FxiOS\/)d\{1,2}/,
                    version: 38,
                    compatibility: ?,
                },
                'opera': {
                    regex: /(?<=OPR\/)\d{1,2}/,
                    version: 30,
                    compatibility: ?,
                },
            };
```

Then I do:

```
                for (let browser in browsers) {
                    Object.defineProperties(browsers[browser], 'compatibility', { // Error at this line
                        writable: true,
                        configurable: true,
                        enumerable: false,
                        value: (() => {
                            if (browser === 'safari') {
                                try {
                                    return getVersion.match([browser].regex)[1] >= [browser].version;
                                } catch {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            } else {
                                return getVersion.match([browser].regex) >= [browser].version;
                            }
                        }) (),
                    });
                };
```

But it throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property description must be an object: c
```

Console shows this error was thrown when defineProperty() was executed and also in jQuery, 
I checked https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/No_non-null_object but not very helpful. 
I would like to know why this happen and what does 'object: c' means. Thx!

Comment: I do not understand what you want to 'add' here. And why do you have questionmarks in your second code snippet? That's a syntax error.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone '?' means the content I add through defineProperty()

Comment: You're not using `Object.defineProperty` as you meant to do. You wrote `Object.defineProperties`, which doesn't work when called with a property name and single descriptor.

Comment: @Bergi Ye I got this typo thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you got complains about the second argument, not the third.

You are calling `defineProperties`, which only expects 2 arguments, where the second must be the plain object. But you call it with the signature that is expected for `defineProperty`. You seem to have confused the two methods, as you go on to write *"...when defineProperty() was executed"*

So change that call into `defineProperty` (singular).

Comment: Yes you are right. I hate vscode autofilling...Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

try as below

```
  for (let browser in browsers) {
                    Object.defineProperties(browsers[browser], {compatibility: { // Error at this line
                        writable: true,
                        configurable: true,
                        enumerable: false,
                        value: (() => {
                            if (browser === 'safari') {
                                try {
                                    return getVersion.match([browser].regex)[1] >= [browser].version;
                                } catch {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            } else {
                                return getVersion.match([browser].regex) >= [browser].version;
                            }
                        }) (),
                    }});
                };
```